# Show by an example that a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in the sandard (order) topology need not be compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

[image: c]

In my mind, I can think of below example which seems to work.

If $(X,T) = \mathbb{R}$, and $A = (0,\infty)$, then as far as I know it comes in the standard (order) topology of $\mathbb{R}$, but what I dont know is whether it will be a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If it works, then it will be perfect b/c for all positive integer $i$, if I let $P_i$ be the open interval $(0,i)$, then clearly $A \subset \cup$ $O_i$, where $i = 1$ to $\infty$,

however there doesnt exist $i_1, i_2,......, i_n$, such that $A \subset (0,i_1),(0,i_2),....,(0,i_n)$, therefore by the definition of compactness we can see that we dont have a finite sub-cover, so its not compact.

Kindly check my proof, let me know if there is anything wrong. Also, give it better style and notation if required.

Comment: $A$ is a proper subset, but it is not closed. However, $[0, \infty)$ is closed in the standard topology of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo it says standard (order) topology, can u show me how its closed in that on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: The complement of $[0, \infty)$ is $(-\infty, 0)$, which is an open interval (and hopefully you've proven that open intervals form a basis for the standard topology). Since the complement is open, it follows that the original set is closed (by definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $(0,\infty)$ is not closed. But $[0,\infty)$ will work. For instance, the sequence $1,2,3,\ldots$ has no convergent subsequence. Or you can say that $\{[0,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: $[0,n)$ is not an open set for any natural $n$.

Comment: I was thinking of this, however $[0,\infty)$ is not a closed proper subset, its a half open interval. Also, how will b the standard (order) topology if I choose that? Standard (order) topology is the topology generated by the sub-basis consisting of positive and negative open rays. Here, I can think of NOR = $(0, \infty)$ but I am not sure whether POR will be $(-\infty, 0)$ or not. Regarding the open and finite sub-cover I will have to check. I am working on that bt I got a doubt before that so thought of asking it.

Comment: @Martund It *is* an open subset of $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I claim that $[0,\infty)$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb R$ and that it is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Do you disagree with any of these assertions?

Comment: But we are considering $\Bbb R$ as the universal set, not $[0,\infty)$. We are viewing $[0,\infty)$ also as a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Martund Then consider $\{(-1,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ instead.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No I dont, I got your idea now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos u can consider  {(−n,n)|n∈N} this instead, this will work perfectly. I have checked it.

Answer (score 2):

Noting that any bounded closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact, so we need to think of unbounded closed subsets like: $$[a,\infty), \mathbb{N}, \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = [0, \infty)$, then its complement $A^c = (-\infty, 0)$ is an open interval, and hence $A^c$ is an open set. Thus, by definition, $A$ is a closed set.

To show it is not compact, consider the following open cover: $\{(-n,n)| \, \, n \in \Bbb{N}\}$. This open cover in fact covers all of $\Bbb{R}$, so in particular covers $A$. Clearly, there is no finite subcover. Hence, $A$ is not compact.

Comment: wat will be the sub-basis of $A$? I guess $(-\infty,0) \cup [0,\infty)$, still correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun why do you need a subbasis?

Comment: just asking, I might have to show that while writing the proof. My prof loves 2 see all d details.

Answer (score 0):

By Heine-Borel, a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is closed and bounded.

So take any closed, unbounded set.